# This works just fine when creating a new record. If I come back to edit this record, it always ends up defaulting to the first one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the ruby on rails code I am using.  I am a newbie to RoR so it is likely something simple but I have spent over an hour looking at the previous questions on this same problem with no solution that works.  Here is my code.

```
<div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="status">Status:</label>
<div class="col-sm-7">
        <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(["Not Scheduled","Scheduled","Completed/Paid", "Need to Reschedule"]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show your full form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the second argument for `options_for_select` to set a default selected option. You have that form taking a new or created model. you want to use the status field of that model for the default

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(["Not Scheduled","Scheduled","Completed/Paid", "Need to Reschedule"], @model.status), {}, class: "form-control" %>
```

if this doesnt make sense to you, please edit in your full form

Comment: you probably meant `@model.status` instead of `@model.select`

Comment: I changed m code to:  <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(["Not Scheduled","Scheduled","Completed/Paid", "Need to Reschedule"], @model.status), {}, class: "form-control" %>            I am getting error message "Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/agss/app/views/appointments/_form.html.erb where line #95 raised:

undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Here is my full form as requested.  I am having this same issue on every field where I am using a select. Trying to add in my entire form but it is not formatting.  How do I present you with my total form code properly formatted?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out with your very good help.  I changed @model.status to appointment.status and that fixed the problem.  Thanks very much!!!